# Without solving the equation, determine the nature of its roots: $x^2 + ax + a^2 = 0$

Tags: self-learning, quadratics

I'm working through the book Core Maths for Advanced Level on my own, and, after solving the above problem, I'm not getting the same answer as the book.

So, given: $$x^2 + ax + a^2 = 0$$

Using the quadratic formula: $a = 1, b = a, c = a^2$.

Therefore, the discriminant is: $$a^2 - 4(1)(a^2) = a^2 - 4a^2 = -3a^2$$

As we're squaring $a$, it will always be non-negative.  However, as we're multiplying by $-3$, the result is always non-positive.  To me, that says that if $a = 0$, there are equal real roots, but if $a$ is not equal to $0$, there are no real roots.  However, the book only gives the answer as being no real roots.

I'm fairly certain I have this right, especially after substituting zero and non-zero values into the original equation, but I wonder if I'm missing something.  Which answer is correct?

Comment: You are correct. If $a = 0$, the quadratic reduces to $x^2 = 0$, which has real root(s) $0, 0$.

Comment: I guess you should pose the problem to the authors: maybe they forgot to consider the case $a=0$. I have the impression this problem is meant to have you observe $x^2+ax+a^2$ is a "fake square", i.e. something that looks like a square of a binomial ($(x+a)^2$ in this case) but has no double product, but rather a single product. Such polynomials don't have real roots, hence the solution. Of course, the degenerate case $a=0$ is an obvious exception and is present since the double and single product are equal. But it's only guesswork :).

Comment: OR it could be you missed an $a\neq0$ hypothesis :). Check for it. If there is none, I suggest you contact the authors for an explanation.

Comment: @taninamdar Thank you.

Comment: @MickG Contacting the authors is a good idea actually.  I hadn't considered that.  There is no qualifier ruling that a is not equal to zero, so it's a definite problem.  This book is 15 years old, but I've never been able to find any published errata for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are correct. $D=-3a^2$ so we have the case where $a=0$ with solutions $x_{1}=x_{2}=0$, otherwise non-real solutions due to the discriminant being negative.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.